# Saving input value to a variable instantly

Tags: javascript, variables, input

*Hello,*

I need to instantly save the value of an input into a variable , adding keyup or keydown event listeners only updates the variable with the previous value of the input.

**Is there any better solution than using setTimeout() ?**

```
document.getElementById('project').addEventListener('keydown', function projectNameVerifyInit() {
  let projectName = document.getElementById('project').value;
  console.log(projectName);
});
```

`<input type="text" name="project" id="project" placeholder="Project Name" autofocus required>`

*Thanks*

Comment: Bind it to the `input` event

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Input event.

```
document.getElementById('project').addEventListener('input', function (evt) {
    let projectName = document.getElementById('project').value;
    console.log(projectName);
})
```